# How to access gpio-keys from a shell script

Tags: embedded, yocto, keyboard-event, gpio, events

In my embedded linux system, I defined some GPIOs as keys in the device tree so I can use them as keys in my application. This works fine so far.

Now I want to add an early startup script to respond to one of those keys before my application starts, but I can't access the gpios via `/sys/class/gpio` anymore, because they are already keys (trying to `export` them gives `write error: Device or resource busy`).

I could install `evtest` or simply read `/dev/input/event0` where I can see key presses and releases, but I can't see a straight forward way to detect a long key press that way in a shell script. Any suggestion how this should be done?

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event

Comment: @gerhardd. Thank you, I'm able to extract the wanted key and whether this is a press or release, just in a shell script I would need to read that device file with half a second timeout after my key was pressed to detect a long press. which seems like an extremely ugly approach.